# Places API - Request more quota for iOS application before launch

Tags: iphone, ios, google-places-api

I am the manager of an iOS application that uses Google Places API to find venues near the location of users. The application has not launched yet on the App Store but my analysis give me good reason to believe that the number of requests I am provided (100,000) will not be enough to support a large user base. This is because each time a user opens the app, 20 venues automatically appear nearest the user and then the user can search for venues within a 40 mile radius. I predict that every user will use approximately 40 request each time the app is opened on the users iPhone. If the use the app twice in one day, then each user will use 80 requests per day. This means that only 1,250 users can access the app in one day before I run out of quota (100,000 requests). This app will be used in large city areas so more than 1,250 will use the app. I do not want to launch my app with only 100,000 requests and it seems that I cannot uplift my quota until the app is launched on the App Store because the Uplift Request Form asks for application download URLs and it cannot be downloaded at this time. Is there a way to receive/request more quota before now before the app is launched?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/uplift) might help you.

Go through this and validate your identity and get more quota.

Comment: I have been to that site and looked at the Uplift Request Form if you scroll to the bottom. This is where it asks me for my application download URLs, which are required. I am not launching the app website until one week before the app launch and the app will not display on the App Store until it is launched. Therefore, I'm not sure how to get more quota before the launch.

Answer (score 0):

I have been to that site and looked at the Uplift Request Form if you scroll to the bottom. This is where it asks me for my application download URLs, which are required. I am not launching the app website until one week before the app launch and the app will not display on the App Store until it is launched. Therefore, I'm not sure how to get more quota before the launch.